# CSS background-image and image of html img tag

Tags: html, css, background-image, image

Does user's browser load the image used for an img tag, and another place used as the background-image of a css class , twice?

- url of the image is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, assuming the URL is exactly the same (including casing), the image will only be downloaded once.

Comment: For reference, it's also based on case too. If both background and img are myImage.png then it will only call to download the image once. If background is myimage.png and img is myImage.png it will call to download the image twice as it will assume the differently-cased images are different.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, newer browsers tend to cache an image when it is first called. So the answer is, no, only once unless it is an older browser.