# Full-Size Background Image: <img> fallback for accessibility and print

Tags: css, image, performance, printing, accessibility

On developing a site with full-sized background images (using the `cover` attribute) I want to supply an additional image in a hidden image tag that appears on print and maybe for accessibility readers.

Right now, I just supply a separate print CSS displaying the image and overriding the background element.

Is there a common solution (maybe involving an ARIA tag) that could be applied?

<del>Also: I shouldn't care about performance implications because the same ressource is re-used, right?</del> See: [Ressource gets only loaded once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526861/css-background-image-and-image-of-html-img-tag?rq=1)

See:

- [Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJmBVG)

Comment: What about ticking the "Print Background Images"(FF) checkbox in the print dialog ? (or "Background Graphics" in Chrome or "Print backgrounds" in Safari or [there might be an option] in IE)

Comment: While this is a good option for the tech-savvy, I suspect not every visitor will know about this preference (which has to my knowledge been introduced not too long ago). 

Also – print CSS uses different layout measures anyway which would profit from regular image scaling (say pagebreaks).

Answer (score 0):

The accessibility requirement for images is to add the text that is in the image in TEXT in the document, not to add another image. What you should be doing is adding a span element with the hidden class and a text of "960 by 540". You should also change the hidden class to:

```
.hidden {
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; width: 1px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
```

So that the screen reader will still pick it up